# Getting specific data from array

Tags: javascript

i have request from backend and get the response

the request is like this

```
cardnof(newValue) {
            this.datakartu.cardno = newValue
            this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://192.168.1.40:5000/getdataemp','POST',{cardno:newValue},null).subscribe((data)=>{ 

                    var rData = [];
                    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    rData.push(data[i]);
                    }
                    console.log(rData);

            });

        }
```

in the console shows data like this

[image]

i want to get the spesific data for example.

rData.Birth_Day,
rData.Full_Name and so on,

any idea?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: This has nothing to do with either Angular or TypeScript. It's just basic JavaScript. Remember that `rData` is an **array**. How do you access the first element of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if it solves.
var result = rData.map(i=> ({ Birth_Day: i.firstname ,Full_Name : i.Full_Name }) );

for single array values try

var result = rData.map(i=> (i.Birth_Day) )

Comment: thx for the answer but i still got object inside object, i cant get the value directly

Comment: can you please give me the format in which you need the answer

Comment: rData is an array, and i want get the specific data like rData.birthday (just the value) birthday : "2017-01-16T09:44:00.000Z"

Comment: Okay you need to get only array like ['bdate1','bdate2','bdate3']

Comment: rData.map(i=> (Birth_Day) ); try this.

Comment: sorry rData.map(i=> (i.Birth_Day) );